# fetch data from URL with password

Tags: ios, ios5

I want to fetch data from this URL: http://webservices.ns.nl/ns-api-stations. This URL requires a login. How to put this login in my code? This code is what I am using now.

-(void)fetchStationData {
    //Method for the fetching of the data

```
//First lets check wheater there is an internet connection and if the host is reachable
if(internetActive) {

    //Internet is active

    //Init the parser
    parser = [[RSSParser alloc] init];

    //Set he parser context
    parser.context = context;

    //The array to het the data from 
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://webservices.ns.nl/ns-api-stations"];

    //The XML elements to fetch
    NSArray *elements = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"naam",nil];

    //The actual fetchin
    [parser fetchStationItemsForUrl:url forElements:elements];

    //Save the context ?
    [context save:nil];

    //Clean up
    [elements release]; 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server which you try to access and fetch some data is requiring a some kind of authentication to allow it.. So before you try to make a get request you need the perform a authentication. So you need to know which kind of authentication method(for example Digest Auth) they're using and also you need a username and password..

Also you need to use HTTPRequest library. I suggest you to use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#specifying_a_username_and_password_to_use_in_the_url), It's really simple.. You can also perform authentication with asihtttprequest library before make a request from a server.

Comment: Works great after adding the frameworks: CFNetwork, SystemConfiguration, MobileCoreServices and the libz. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The website you linked is protected by [basic auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). One of the simpler ways to pass the authentication information would be to append the credentials to the URL:

```
http://user:password@webservices.ns.nl/ns-api-stations
```

Note that the website is not protected with SSL, so all authentication information will be passed in the clear.